# Position absolute dropdown in scrollable container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make the position absolute dropdown stay on top of the scrollable container, and move along with the position relative parent when scrolling? Right now, the dropdown appears within the scrollable area.

The screenshot below is what I want to achieve. I'm also open to javascript solutions if needed.

[image]

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkqgnxff/)**

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px black;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-item {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navbar-item">
    <a>Item A</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item A</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item B</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item B</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item C</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item D</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item E</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Personally I would have the navigation outside of the scrollable container and wrap the entire nav in a header div with a position of fixed and a top of 0 then have other elements below!

Comment: Out of interest, when would a user be simultaneously expanding the menu and scrolling horizontally?

Comment: @PhillipDews Are you able to make an example based on the fiddle? Also want to point out that the navbar isn't in the site header, it will be used in a section in the middle of the page.

Comment: @sol Good question, I think it will be hidden when the dropdown moves outside of the viewport, or I can set overflow hidden on the outer container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using jQuery.

Basically, as others have mentioned, you'll have to move the subnav items outside of the main nav's wrapper, so that they are not hidden.

We can put them in their own wrapper that has a similar markup to the main nav's wrapper, and then match them up using a data element to allow for showing/hiding on click.

Then, when we scroll the main navbar, we can sync the subnav wrapper to that element's scroll position, so the subnav items appear to be fixed to the main nav items.

Lastly, we can hide the subnav wrapper's scroll bar with CSS.

The snippet below should get you the general idea, then you can style it as necessary to make it look more like the primary and secondary nav items are connected.

Click a nav item in the main nav, then scroll to the side to see it in action:

```js
$(function(){
 var navbar = $('.navbar');
  var subnavBar = $('.subnavs-wrapper .scrollbar-hider');

  $(navbar).find('li').each(function(){
    var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var matchingUl = $(this).parent().next().find('ul[data-id="' + dataId + '"]');
    $(this).on('click', function(){
      $(matchingUl).css('visibility') == 'hidden' ?
      $(matchingUl).css('visibility', 'visible') : $(matchingUl).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    
  $(navbar).on('scroll', function(){
      $(subnavBar).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });
 });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px black;
  display: none;
}

.navbar-item {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.subnavs-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden; /* hide scrollbar */
}

.subnavs-wrapper .scrollbar-hider {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* hide scrollbar */
  margin-bottom: -50px; /* hide scrollbar */
}

.subnav {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navbar-item" data-id="one"><a>Item A</a>
  <li class="navbar-item" data-id="two"><a>Item B</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item" data-id="three"><a>Item C</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item" data-id="four"><a>Item D</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item" data-id="five"><a>Item E</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="subnavs-wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar-hider">
    <ul class="subnav" data-id="one">
      <li>Sub Item A.A</li>
      <li>Sub Item A.B</li>
      <li>Sub Item A.C</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="subnav" data-id="two">
      <li><a>Sub Item B.A</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="subnav" data-id="three">
      <li><a>Sub Item C.A</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub Item C.B</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="subnav" data-id="four">
      <li><a>Sub Item D.A</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub Item D.B</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="subnav" data-id="five">
      <li><a>Sub Item E.A</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub Item E.B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to make the position of dropdown fixed, but make sure to apply the left and top values accordingly. Another way is to append the dropdown menu outside the ul element, so when it appears it will not be wrapped within it.

```
.dropdown {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px black;
  display: none;
}

.navbar-item {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navbar-item">
    <a>Item A</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item A</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item B</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item B</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item C</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item D</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item E</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**

I added one more snippet that does not use fixed position. It changes its coordinates when open based on the parent offset.

```js
$('#menu1, #submenu1').mouseover(function(event) {
  $('#submenu1').addClass("show").css($('#menu1').offset());
});

$('#menu1, #submenu1').mouseleave(function(event) {
  $('#submenu1').removeClass("show");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px black;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.show {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-item {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar">
  <li id="menu1" class="navbar-item">
    <a>Item A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item B</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item C</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item D</a></li>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a>Item E</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="submenu1" class="dropdown">
  <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item A</li>
  <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item B</li>
  <li class="dropdown-item">Sub Item C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When the dropdown is set to position fixed it will no longer move with parent item when scrolling; and once you apply left, top value it will then relative to the viewport not the parent item.

Comment: I added one more snippet that does not use fixed position. It changes its coordinates when open based on the parent offset.